# Unable to read and send the request simultaneously in java using serversocket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, stream, server

I have written this simple java server which is ready to accept connections on a port using server sockets.
I want that whenever some client tries to send some data on this port within same local network I want to:

1.print that data ie: read from inputstream using `InputStreamReader` into a buffer and then print into console.

2.send some data back to the client by writing on outputstream using `OutPutStreamWriter`.

3.close both the streams ie: `outputStreamWriter` and `inputStreamReader` and then finally close the socket.

The problem which I am facing is that I am able to do only one at a time even though I have created two separate threads for both input and output.

Example if  I fire a request on port `8086` from any device within the same network everything gets blocked (mabye a deadlock) nothing is printed onto the console unless the client who made the request itself cancels the request.
similarly if I terminate the connection from server ie: terminate the java application then on the client side I get this response string "success".

I don't know why the streams are not getting closed after the process even though I have closed them.

I thought if we write onto `outputstream` and read in from `inputstream` in two different threads it would solve the problem but still no luck.

Can anybody help?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class Notification {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader buffInputStream;
    private InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter;
    private OutputStream outputstream;
    private InputStream inputstream;
    public Notification(){

    }


    public void start() {

        Thread listenThread = new Thread(listen);
        listenThread.start();
    }

    Runnable listen = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8086);
                while(true){
                    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                    Thread t2 = new Thread(inStream);
                    t2.start();

                    Thread t1 = new Thread(outStream);
                    t1.start();

                    t1.join();
                    t2.join();

                    buffInputStream.close();
                    inputStreamReader.close();
                    outputStreamWriter.close();
                    clientSocket.close();

                }
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    Runnable outStream = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                outputstream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream);
                outputStreamWriter.write("success");
                outputStreamWriter.flush();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    Runnable inStream = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                inputstream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);

                buffInputStream = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                List<String> response = new ArrayList<>();

                String line;
                while ((line = buffInputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.add(line);
                }

                String arr[] = response.toArray(new String[response.size()]);

                for (String re : arr) {
                    System.out.println(re);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no deadlock here. Your read thread simply isn't printing anything until the peer disconnects. Print each line as you read it, not after end-of-stream is received. You don't have any need for the list, or the array, or the second loop.

But this will never work. You're sharing a single `clientSocket` reference among all clients. You need to create `Runnables` that take the client socket as a parameter and store it as an instance variable.